# How to optimize the travel path

Tags: print-quality

This model is essentially a cylinder. However, about mid-way, I break up the cylinder wall into multiple segments, while pretty much keeping to the general shape of a cylinder. Two segments per 90-degree section.

Cura has left one quadrant essentially alone. However, in the other three, it prints a segment, travels to a new quadrant, repeats until the layer is complete. The optimal path would be: print the center strip, print the perimeter, move a couple of millimeters, and repeat 8x. Essentially walking around the cylinder wall of each layer.

Are there any programs to help with this? My Google-Fu isn't the best. My searches resulted in Cura travel settings, where I already modified a few settings and can't find any that change the travel path.

Aside from a reduction in print time, the areas where the travel occurs leaves some artifacts I'd rather not have. I reduced my travel speed and increased my retraction. Instead of "sticks", I have bumps, like a mini-seam. ("Sticks" - Literally short segments of filament stuck to the cylinder wall, not hairs.)

I guess there are two routes to improving the quality here: travel / other settings. I'm essentially "blaming" travel on my problems and hence focused on it.

What I consider standard quality:
[image: Photo of a 3D printed model with printing errors]

What I'm trying to avoid:
[image: Photo of the same 3D printed model without the printing errors]

Printer: Creality Ender 3 S1 Pro - 0.5 Steel
Filament: HIPS
Nozzle temp: 265 °C
Bed temp: 110 °C
Slicer: Cura 5.2.1
Layer Height: 0.3 mm
Inner / Outer Walls: 0.75 mm | 0.7 mm (> 0.7 yields unaligned seam?)
Inner / Outer wall speed: 55 mm/s | 45 mm/s
Retraction: 1 mm | 45 mm/s
Travel speed: 200 mm/s